# How can I get the stemlines color to match the marker color in a stem plot?

Tags: matplotlib

Stem lines are always blue:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
x = np.linspace(0.1, 2*np.pi, 10)

plt.stem(x, np.sin(x), markerfmt='o', label='sin')
plt.stem(x+0.05, np.cos(x), markerfmt='o', label='cos')
plt.legend()

plt.show()
```

produce:
[image: stem lines don't match markers]

I want the stem lines to match the color of the markers (blue for the first dataset, green for the second).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can add a formatting argument for each stem as you'd do for `plot`.  Note the `'b'` and `'g'` arguments in the `plt.stem` calls below.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
x = np.linspace(0.1, 2*np.pi, 10)

#                            v---------- add these args
plt.stem(x,      np.sin(x), 'b', markerfmt='bo', label='sin')
plt.stem(x+0.05, np.cos(x), 'g', markerfmt='go', label='cos')
plt.legend()

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

One way of solving this is to modify the stem lines after the call to `plt.stem`. We can obtain the color of the marker using `plt.getp(..., 'color')` and use `plt.setp` to assign that color to the stem lines:

```
x = np.linspace(0.1, 2*np.pi, 10)

markerline, stemlines, baseline = plt.stem(x, np.sin(x), markerfmt='o', label='sin')
plt.setp(stemlines, 'color', plt.getp(markerline,'color'))
plt.setp(stemlines, 'linestyle', 'dotted')


markerline, stemlines, baseline = plt.stem(x+0.05, np.cos(x), markerfmt='o', label='cos')
plt.setp(stemlines, 'color', plt.getp(markerline,'color'))
plt.setp(stemlines, 'linestyle', 'dotted')

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

produces:

[image: stem lines match the marker]

Comment: Thanks for this idea.

Answer (score 5):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [210 , 420, 630,840]
y = [1, 1, 1,1]
z = [100 , 200, 300,400]
plt.xlim(0,1000)
plt.ylim(-2,2)
markerline, stemlines, baseline = plt.stem(x, y, markerfmt='o', label='pcd')
plt.setp(stemlines, 'color', plt.getp(markerline,'color'))
plt.setp(stemlines, 'linestyle', 'dotted')

markerline, stemlines, baseline = plt.stem(z, y, markerfmt='go', label='can')
plt.setp(stemlines, 'color', plt.getp(markerline,'color'))
plt.setp(stemlines, 'linestyle', 'dotted')

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]